# Get and redirect URL from result of scan QR code

Tags: android

I'm a new android.
I have a simple application for scan QR code. But it only show result.

[My picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trpbm.jpg)

I want it get url from this result and redirect to it

This is my code.

MainActivity.java

```
package app.num.barcodescannerproject;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

import com.google.zxing.Result;
import me.dm7.barcodescanner.zxing.ZXingScannerView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler {
private ZXingScannerView mScannerView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}

public void QrScanner(View view){


    mScannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this);   // Programmatically initialize the scanner view
    setContentView(mScannerView);

    mScannerView.setResultHandler(this); // Register ourselves as a handler for scan results.
    mScannerView.startCamera();         // Start camera

}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mScannerView.stopCamera();           
}

@Override
public void handleResult(Result rawResult) {
    // Do something with the result here

    Log.e("handler", rawResult.getText());
    Log.e("handler", rawResult.getBarcodeFormat().toString());

    // show the scanner result into dialog box.
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Result");
    builder.setMessage(rawResult.getText());
    AlertDialog alert1 = builder.create();
    alert1.show();


   mScannerView.resumeCameraPreview(this);
}
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="app.num.barcodescannerproject">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Please help me. Thank all